# Join MySQL tables unknown number of times

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table of client information.  I have another table with items they can choose from.  I have a third table that lists the items the client has selected.  Each client can select zero or more items.

e.g.

```
Client Table:
clientID
clientName
...

Item Table:
itemID
itemName

Purchase Table:
purchaseID
clientID
itemID
```

I know I can have a query that grabs all the clients and then for each one, run a query that will grab the user-friendly names of all the items they selected (if any).

Is there a way that I can write one query to grab the client information and all the items they selected?  If they could only select one item, I'd just do a left join, however since they can select multiple items, I'm unsure how to do that.

My goal is to have something like this:

```
Client Name | Item Name | Item Name | Item Name | ...
John | Shoes | <empty> | <empty>
Claire | Shoes | Socks | <empty>
Marie | <empty> | Socks | Shirts
```

Comment: Could you post the two queries you say you have? (or that you are capable of writing)

Comment: Try the left join, it'll work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I didnt understand the question fully but a standard join will return only matching values so i assume from your results thats what you dont want. If you left join clients as mentioned above this will return all clients regardless of whether they have any items or purchases which is a similar result to your example.

```
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM CLIENT C
    LEFT JOIN Purchase P ON C.clientID = P.clientID
    JOIN Item I on I.itemID = P.itemID;
```

Comment: This is kind of what I'd want, except it has multiple rows for each client.  Ideally I'd like to have one row for each client, and that row will have itemName fields at the end of the row.  So if the client selected one item, it would have a field at the end with that item.  If the client selected two items, it will have two fields at the end indicating each item.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, use group by for each column.

Comment: It should already show you that information, if you "order by" the results by name it will show you everything that person has purchased together. You could then choose to group it etc

Comment: @raphael-müllner sorry for rejecting your edit, didn't notice the missing `C` that you had added!